# ASP.NET Session state lost after exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've usually avoided in-proc session state, until this recent project. I think I have a problem where the state is lost after an unhandled exception occurs.

This in itself is odd, since exceptions in the context of a request don't down the worker process. It could be an exception on a background thread or a callback or something but, this is a simple site and there's nothing fancy going on.

The session ID remains the same and Session_Start is not called on the subsequent request (so the WP hasn't recycled).

I have quite a lot of logging enabled, and its plain to see that I get an exception from the data tier, its an HttpException inside a HttpUnhandleException, then when I browse immediately after to the home page, the request logs a warning about the missing state.

Worse. This doesn't happen on my dev box (IIS Express), only in QA.

Edit:

Here's a chunk of log:

```
2013-06-12 13:44:29,975 [23] FATAL MvcApplication 100.100.100.100 pxtgn GET An unhandled exception occurred in the web application. The full exception will be unrolled below.
2013-06-12 13:44:30,897 [23] FATAL MvcApplication 100.100.100.100 pxtgn GET Exception.Type: HttpUnhandledException
Exception.Source: System.Web
Exception.Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Exception.StackTrace:    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.InvokeCancellableCallback(WaitCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LegacyAsyncPageBeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

    Exception.Type:     HttpException
    Exception.Source:     CompanyNameProductName.MvcCoreApp
    Exception.Message:     An error was reported by the data layer: 0Image not found1-10.1007_978-1-4471-4294-2_21-16
    Exception.StackTrace:        at CompanyName.CompanyNameProductName.imagedetail.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\DATA\Git\ProductName\CompanyNameProductNameMvc\imagedetail.aspx.cs:line 55
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


2013-06-12 13:45:07,913 [25] DEBUG StandardPage 100.100.100.100 pxtgn GET Initializing page 'default_aspx' for GET with query string: 
2013-06-12 13:45:07,913 [25] ERROR StandardPage 100.100.100.100 pxtgn GET No User instance in session state. Check the log for signs that the session was started properly since a User object should aways exist in session state, setup via session start events in ASP.NET.
```

The last line shows the missing state condition. The pxtgn is the first 5 chars from the session ID. I hit a page for which I know the data layer will barf about the non-existent image ID. Then any page I hit next will cause my check to log the problem with the missing state. The check and state reference is in the code for the master page, so I can hit any page to see the problem. This also means the custom error page doesn't work - which is sort of how I came to find the bug.

I've now added a `Session.Abandon()` after the check and respond with a 500 to get me out of jail, but its quite an odd problem. I'm new to the codebase, and I think I've checked everywhere for the session being cleared or state being overwritten.

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint inside `Application_Start`? Is this called again?

Comment: Is the site load balanced? Do you use Webgarden?

Comment: @Darin - its not called. There's logging there, too, it seems the WP stays up.

Comment: @Malcolm - not in QA, in prod its a 4-node farm with sticky sessions on the NLB. Not sure if there's an issue in prod since there's no logging (my added logging has picked this issue up).

Comment: Use fiddler and see if the session cookie maybe lost between these posts. It may be that the old session is still there, but with the cookie lost, the next request is assigned a new session.

Comment: @David The Session_Start isn't called, but I love the idea. I'll look into it when I'm back on that project.

Answer (score -3):

1 Thread is destroyed
2 Asynchronous environment

use httpcontext as a Parameter
not system.web.****.httpcontext

Comment: Please put a but more effort into answering. Write whole sentences with punctuation, make sure the formatting is correct. Above all, please explain *why* this answers the question.